nextjs front-end flooded with connection errors - is this normal behavior?
I am working on connecting a simple solo chain to a front end built on next.js. Using current educational material and PAPI, I have managed to import a chain-connected component to my webapp. The simple component functions and displays the latest block number:

When I open the developer console, this is what I am greeted with:

The 1000:: Normal Closure makes me think this is normal async behavior being caught and logged in the component's useEffect():

If this is normal behavior, is there a correct way to silence or hide the log?

Did you open the rpc port on the node side?

I moved the substrate solo chain to a different machine on my LAN. I use ./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp --rpc-external to start the chain node. I use npm run dev on localhost for the front end node. Since moving the Blockchain to another machine, I receive less closure errors, but still some. I imagine it has to do with switching and traffic on our network.

Did you try --rpc-cors all?

--rpc-cors all did the trick. Thanks!

Make sure you have configured these setting for development node to expose the port.
--rpc-methods unsafe --rpc-external --rpc-cors all

I suspect you are using either a localhost RPC or an incorrect RPC, which is likely causing the Normal Closure error

Localhost RPC. I guess upgrading the homelab needs to be higher up on the Todo list.
